# cannot start grass modules in gqis 2.14

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

When wanting to use the different modules in GRASS 7.2.1 I get this error. The version of qgis is 2.14.17 on 64 bit windows.

[image: The error that comes up]

I already checked that grass can find the right provider folder path.

Who knows how to get grass working?

Comment: Does the GRASS GUI work outside QGIS, and/or within the processing toolbox? Have you opened a GRASS project?

Comment: No it does not. When i start GRASS outside of Qgis and want to open a project i get the following: 'process ended with non-zero return code -107374151'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [GRASS wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WinGRASS_errors#Error_message_.22Process_ended_with_non-zero_return_code_-1073741571.22) , this is a Windows-only bug, if the region is too large:

```
This error message may indicate that the Computational region region is
containing too many pixels.

Background: according to StackOverflow this number "is the signed
integer representation of Microsoft's 'stack overflow/stack exhaustion'
error code 0xC00000FD."

To verify:

g.region -p

The mount of "cells" main exceed that being manageable by your computer:
in case if this error message the number of rows/columns is likely too
high. Either reduce the extent or lower the resolution.
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this is the case, because there isn't any map loaded yet. And in the mapset for GRASS the region i defined is the size of ivory coast, and that is not too big a region when working on another computer.

Comment: It is not the extent, but the resolution that kills the application. In the OSGEO Shell, can you navigate to your GISBASE/LOCATION_NAME folder, then run `grass72 -text <mapsetname>` and `g.region -p`?

Comment: I'm affraid that I don't know how to execute your solution... Where is this OSGEO Shell, is it the shell that's on top of the module list when you open GRASS in Qgis?
And what do i have to type to navigate to my location folder in this shell?
Thanks by the way for all your suggestions, even if it all doesn't work out I'm grateful for your help!

Comment: The shell is one of the icons you get when you install QGIS on Windows. Navigating must be done with `cd \<foldername> ` typing by hand.